# How do you send multiple objects using pickle using socket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, pickle

```
#SERVER
import socket
from _thread import *
from plyer import Player, FootBall
import pickle


class GameServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Server = '127.0.0.1'
        self.Port = 52674
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.PlayerId = 0
        st1 = Player(630, 375, (255, 0, 0), 'Arsenal', 'ST')
        lw1 = Player(900, 300, (255, 0, 0), 'Arsenal', 'CB')
        rw1 = Player(370, 300, (255, 0, 0), 'Arsenal', 'RW')
        st2 = Player(630, 300, (0, 255, 0), 'Spurs', 'ST')
        lw2 = Player(370, 425, (0, 255, 0), 'Spurs', 'CB')
        rw2 = Player(900, 425, (0, 255, 0), 'Spurs', 'RW')
        self.football = FootBall(630, 375) <-- Object I wish to send to both players
        self.Player1_slot = st1
        self.Player2_slot = st2

        self.p = [self.Player1_slot, self.Player2_slot]  # Players that are currently being used

    def Bind(self):
        # Connects the client to the server
        try:
            self.s.bind((self.Server, self.Port))
        except socket.error:
            print("Error")

        # Listens to maximum 2 players only
        self.s.listen(2)
        print("Waiting for a connection...")

    def ReturnSocket(self):
        return self.s

    def ThreadedClient(self, conn, curr_player):
        conn.send(pickle.dumps(self.p[curr_player])) <--- Objects I am currently able to send to both players
        #conn.send(pickle.dumps(self.football))

        while True:
            # Continuously runs when the client is connected
            try:
                pos_data = pickle.loads(conn.recv(2048))
                self.p[curr_player] = pos_data

                if not pos_data:
                    print("Player Left")
                    break
                else:
                    if curr_player == 1:
                        reply = self.p[0]
                    else:
                        reply = self.p[1]

                    reply2 = self.football

                    print("[PLAYER] Received: ", pos_data)
                    print("[BALL] Received", reply2)
                    print("[PLAYER] Sending: ", reply)

                conn.sendall(pickle.dumps(reply))
                #conn.sendall(pickle.dumps(reply2))
            except:
                break

        print("Connection Lost")
        conn.close()


def main():
    GS = GameServer()
    GS.Bind()
    while True:
        s = GS.ReturnSocket()
        # Continuously looking for connections
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print(addr, "has joined the game")

        # Function runs in the background
        start_new_thread(GS.ThreadedClient, (conn, GS.PlayerId))
        GS.PlayerId += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

#CLIENT
import socket
import pickle


class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.host = '127.0.0.1'
        self.port = 52674
        self.addr = (self.host, self.port)
        self.p = self.Connect()
        print(self.p)

    def ReturnP(self):
        return self.p

    def Connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(4096))
        except:
            pass

    def Send(self, data):
        try:
            print(data)
            self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
            reply = pickle.loads(self.client.recv(4096))
            return reply
        except socket.error as e:
            return str(e)
```

I would like to send the self.football class to a client alongside with the current classes I have already sent. I have tried doing sendall.pickle.dumps(self.football) however the football does not send. How can I make it so that when it is sent it is separate to the other classes. Thank you in advanced

Comment: What do you mean by "football does not send"? Do you ask how to to send multiple objects through the socket?

Comment: @TheLogicGuy yes I do not understand it

Comment: you send `self.football` as separated `pickle` so client has to load it using second `loads()`. OR you should put all in one list or dictionary and send all as single `pickle`

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the socket in a file-like object via `socket.makefile`, you can read pickled objects directly from the socket.  Here's an example:

```py
import socket
import threading
import pickle

class Football:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Football(a={self.a}, b={self.b})'

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Player(name={self.name!r})'

def server():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('', 5000))
    s.listen()
    with s:
        c, a = s.accept()
        print(f'{a}: connected')
        with c, c.makefile('rb') as r: # make a file-like object to be used directly by pickle
            while True:
                try:
                    obj = pickle.load(r)
                except EOFError: # caused by client close
                    break
                print(obj)
            print(f'{a}: disconnected')

threading.Thread(target=server).start()

# client

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('localhost', 5000))
# buffering=0 sends pickle.dump immediately,
# otherwise need w.flush() or with exit to ensure it is sent
with s, s.makefile('wb', buffering=0) as w:
    f = Football(1,2)
    p1 = Player('Mark')
    p2 = Player('Joe')
    pickle.dump(f, w)
    pickle.dump(p1, w)
    pickle.dump(p2, w)
```

Output:

```
('127.0.0.1', 28974): connected
Football(a=1, b=2)
Player(name='Mark')
Player(name='Joe')
('127.0.0.1', 28974): disconnected
```

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* assume the `recv(2048)` will read the entire pickled object. TCP does not respect message boundaries.

There are other ways to handle this, but it's often done by prefacing each chunk of data with a fixed-length field providing the length of the variable length field. In other words, call `pickle.dumps`, find the length of the resulting data, send a 32-bit (say) binary field containing that length (in python, that usually involves the `struct` module), *then* send the pickled data.

On the receiving side, first read the 32-bit field, then read as many bytes as it tells you, ensuring you loop and continue receiving until you have the entire thing. Only then `pickle.loads` on it.

Note that `recv(2048)` receives *up to* 2048 bytes. But it may also return just 1 or 10 or 200 bytes -- depending on how much data is available in the local OS buffer at that instant.