# No data being sent python socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking, pickle

Working on a game in python and got around to trying to add online multiplayer. Currently working on sending the map, however facing a problem where no data is being received when client connects to the server.

Followed some tutorials online for setting up basic client-server, and used pickle to serialize my tile map to send back to the client. However, nothing is being received even though to me it seems like it should be, and the server is attempting to send it. Tile is simply an object with details on the tile in the tile map, the number being the type of terrain.

Server:

```
# Handles the sending of information to clients such as the map, other unit's sprites, damage, etc
import socket
from _thread import *
import pickle
import random
from Tile import Tile
# Map gen  0 = Plain  1 = Forest  2 = Hill  3 = river   4 = Bridge
def genMap():
    map = [[Tile(0)] * 100 for _ in range(100)]
    for column in range(99): # Generate forest
        for row in range(99):
            if (random.randint(0, 100) < 2): # Centre forest tile roll
                map[column][row] = Tile(1)
                if (random.randint(0, 100) < 65 and column != 98):
                    map[column+1][row] = Tile(1)
                    map[column+2][row] = Tile(1)
                    if (random.randint(0, 100) < 45 and column != 97):
                        map[column+3][row] = Tile(1)
                if (random.randint(0, 100) < 65 and row != 98):
                    map[column][row+1] = Tile(1)
                    map[column][row+2] = Tile(1)
                    if (random.randint(0, 100) < 65 and column != 98):
                        map[column+1][row+1] = Tile(1)
                        map[column+2][row+1] = Tile(1)
                        map[column+1][row+2] = Tile(1)
                        map[column+2][row+2] = Tile(1)
                        if (random.randint(0, 100) < 45 and column != 97):
                            map[column+3][row+1] = Tile(1)
                            map[column+3][row+2] = Tile(1)
                    if (random.randint(0, 100) < 45 and row != 97):
                        map[column][row+3] = Tile(1)
                        if (random.randint(0, 100) < 65 and column != 98):
                            map[column + 1][row + 3] = Tile(1)
                            map[column + 2][row + 3] = Tile(1)
                            if (random.randint(0, 100) < 45 and column != 97):
                                map[column+3][row + 3] = Tile(1)

    for column in range(99): # Generate Hill
        for row in range(99):
            if (random.randint(0, 100) <= 0): # Centre hill tile roll
                map[column][row] = Tile(2)
                if (random.randint(0, 100) < 65 and column != 98):
                    map[column+1][row] = Tile(2)
                    map[column+2][row] = Tile(2)
                    if (random.randint(0, 100) < 45 and column != 97):
                        map[column+3][row] = Tile(2)
                if (random.randint(0, 100) < 65 and row != 98):
                    map[column][row+1] = Tile(2)
                    map[column][row+2] = Tile(2)
                    if (random.randint(0, 100) < 65 and column != 98):
                        map[column+1][row+1] = Tile(2)
                        map[column+2][row+1] = Tile(2)
                        map[column+1][row+2] = Tile(2)
                        map[column+2][row+2] = Tile(2)
                        if (random.randint(0, 100) < 45 and column != 97):
                            map[column+3][row+1] = Tile(2)
                            map[column+3][row+2] = Tile(2)
                    if (random.randint(0, 100) < 45 and row != 97):
                        map[column][row+3] = Tile(2)
                        if (random.randint(0, 100) < 65 and column != 98):
                            map[column + 1][row + 3] = Tile(2)
                            map[column + 2][row + 3] = Tile(2)
                            if (random.randint(0, 100) < 45 and column != 97):
                                map[column+3][row + 3] = Tile(2)

    for column in range(100): # Generate middle river with bridge
        if column == 20 or column == 49 or column == 50 or column == 51 or column == 80: #Bridge
            map[column][51] = Tile(4)
            map[column][50] = Tile(4)
            map[column][49] = Tile(4)
        else: #River
            map[column][51] = Tile(3)
            map[column][50] = Tile(3)
            map[column][49] = Tile(3)
    return map


server = "localhost"
port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.bind((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
    str(e)
s.listen(2)
print("Server started, waiting for connections... ")
map = genMap()
def threaded_client(conn, player, map):
    reply = ""
    while True:
        try:
            s.sendall(pickle.dumps(map))
        except:
            break

    print("Lost connection")
    conn.close()

currentPlayer = 0
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to:", addr)
    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn, currentPlayer, map))
    currentPlayer += 1
```

Network:

```
# Handles methods used for networking
import socket
import pickle
class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "localhost"
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.p = self.connect()
    def connect(self):
        attempts = 0
        while (attempts < 100):
            try:
                self.client.connect(self.addr)
                return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
            except:
                attempts += 1
```

Main (Just two relevant lines right now):

```
n = Network()
map = n.p
```

Map should become the map that is being sent, however is becoming nothing.

Comment: another problem is expecting `self.client.recv(2048)` to contain the complete pickle dump. `recv` can return 1-2048 bytes. It will probably mostly work but the right network conditions can cause failure.

Comment: See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73695840/235698).  I recommend using the `threading` module instead of the low-level `_thread`.

Comment: Don’t ignore exceptions silently. You’re getting one. Print it and post it here, in your question. NB Once a `connect()` has failed the socket is no longer valid and must be closed.

Comment: Don't use pickle for networking.  See the giant red box on https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies in this function. You should be using conn.sendall and not s.sendall. As one of the comments suggested you should also be printing the errors to give you more info on what is going on. Since I am unable to see your tile code I don't know how to reproduce your exact setup. If you could provide that I can answer better.

```
def threaded_client(conn, player, map):
    try:
        conn.sendall(pickle.dumps(map))  # Send the map once
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(2048)  # Listen for data from the client
            if not data:
                break  # If no data, exit the loop
            # Process incoming data and potentially send responses
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
    finally:
        print("Lost connection")
        conn.close()



class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "localhost"
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.map = self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(4096))  # Adjust the buffer size if necessary
        except Exception as e:
            print("Connection Error:", e)

# Main
n = Network()
map = n.map
```

Comment: I tried this but is still returning nothing.