# socket pickle setup hangs during streaming

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, pickle

I am trying to stream a large numpy array from server to client multiple times (using while loop). But it would just sit hanging without doing anything.
I am using python 3.11 with pickle protocol 5.

This is the server:

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import pickle
import time

s = socket.socket()
print("Socket successfully created")

port = 12345
s.bind(('', port))
print("socket binded to %s" % (port))

s.listen(5)
print("socket is listening")

c, addr = s.accept()
print('Got connection from', addr)

try:

    while True:

        x = np.random.random([100, 100, 2])
        data = pickle.dumps(x)
        c.sendall(pickle.dumps(x))

        ack = c.recv(1024)
        if not ack:
            break


except ConnectionResetError:
    print('Connection reset by peer')
    time.sleep(5)

finally:
    c.close()
    s.close()
```

this is the client -

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import pickle
import time

s = socket.socket()

port = 12347

try:
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))

    while True:
        data = b""
        chunk_size = 1024

        while True:
            chunk = s.recv(chunk_size)

            if not chunk:
                break
            data += chunk

        print(pickle.loads(data).nbytes)

        # Send acknowledgment to the server
        s.sendall(b'ACK')

except ConnectionResetError:
    print('Connection reset by peer')
    time.sleep(5)

finally:
    s.close()
```

This setup would work if communication happens only once, that is without the infinite while loop for server and client but doesn't work otherwise.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wrap the socket in a file-like object and read the pickles from that. No need to ack as well. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73695840/235698) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

The client code is waiting for an end-of-stream (TCP FIN) indication at

```py
if not chunk:
    break
```

to know when the server has finished sending, but you never send one from the server until the client sends a reply back. This creates a deadlock where the client and server are each waiting forever for the other to send something. The simplest fix I can think of is to *explicitly* shutdown the WRITE side of the server connection after sending the data, e.g.

```py
# ... <previous code omitted> ...
    c= socket.socket()
    x = np.random.random([100, 100, 2])
    data = pickle.dumps(x)
    c.sendall(pickle.dumps(x))
    c.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)  # this is the new code

    ack = c.recv(1024)
    if not ack:
        break
```

The only change is the addition of the line `c.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)`.